# How to get common language effect size (CLES) with paired groups

Tags: effect-size, paired-comparisons

Common language effect size (CLES : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Common_language_effect_size) is calculated as proportion of all possible pairs of 2 group values which are more for one group than the other. But if 2 groups are paired, then it does not make sense to have all possible pairs of values of 2 groups. How is CLES calculated for paired data? Or is it not possible to use CLES for paired data and one can only report paired t-test for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For paired data, I would say to use only the pairs that you have, not all possible pairs. That makes logical sense.

[Kerby (2014)](http://www.amsciepub.com/doi/pdf/10.2466/11.IT.3.1) (from the Wikipedia reference) says

> McGraw and Wong (1992) discussed using the proportion of favorable pairs as a measure of effect size, which they  called  the  common  language  effect  size.

Comment: How can we calculate confidence limits of CLES with paired data?

Comment: @rnso To get confidence limits, I suggest using binomial confidence intervals. To loosely explain this, if Group A wins Group B 55% of the time, in n occurrences (pairs), what is the distribution p (winning probability)? There are different variations of this, but I generally use and recommend Wilson binomial confidence interval.